# Why do I get the error: TypeError in UsersController#create can't convert String into Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, methods

I am trying to implement a email functionality so that when someone registers they recieve an email. I am following this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

But I get the error:

```
TypeError in UsersController#create
can't convert String into Hash
```

application_mailer.rb:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default "from@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://localhost:3000/users/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %></h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is: <%= @user.login %>.<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

views/user_mailer/welcome_email.txt.erb

```
Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %>
===============================================

You have successfully signed up to example.com,
your username is: <%= @user.login %>.

To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.

Thanks for joining and have a great day!
```

And the create method in users_controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
  # login is achieved by saving a user's 'id' in a session variable, 
  # accessible to all pages
   UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  redirect_to films_path
else
  render action: "new"
end
end
```

User_params in user_controller:

```
def user_params 
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :role, :first_name, :last_name, :house_no, :street, :town, :postcode, :email, :date_of_birth) 
end
```

Full error:

```
TypeError in UsersController#create
can't convert String into Hash
Extracted source (around line #0):           

Rails.root: C:/Sites/Thor/Under Construction/ThorCinema/new/Lab/ThorCinema
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/mailers/application_mailer.rb:2:in `<class:ApplicationMailer>'
app/mailers/application_mailer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:33:in `create'
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: which Rails version are you using? If you are using rails 3, then you can't pass ``@user`` as such, you have to pass the ``@user.id`` and then load the user from your mailer.

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2.0

Comment: can you show ``user_params``, also rest of the error. Like which number exactly mentions that string cannot be converted to hash

Comment: @Coderhs I've added the `user_params` and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default` references a hash in ActionMailer

So this line is incorrect since it specifies a string instead of a hash

```
default "from@example.com"
```

It should be

```
default sender: "from@example.com"
```

See the section "Default Hash" in

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

EDIT

Note that your full trace even points out the line for you...

app/mailers/application_mailer.rb:2:in `'